# How to insert DateTime in MySql WorkBench using java?

Tags: java, mysql

How can I store data time in my SQL Work Bench using java?
I tried by Failed to do so.
Want to insert current Date time in Order Column using Java

```
insert into customer_order (idCustomer_Order,Customer_id,Total_Amount,Payment,Order_date,Order_month,Order_year,Delivery_date,Delivery_month,Delivery_year,product_id,OrderDate)value(3,1,122,'payed',3,2,4,2,3,4,4,curdate())
```

i tried this but  time is 00:00:00
3   1   122 payed   3   2   4   2   3   4   4   2017-12-28 00:00:00

Comment: insert into customer_order (idCustomer_Order,Customer_id,Total_Amount,Payment,Order_date,Order_month,Order_year,Delivery_date,Delivery_month,Delivery_year,product_id,OrderDate)value(3,1,122,'payed',3,2,4,2,3,4,4,curdate())

i tried this but time is 00:00:00 3 1 122 payed 3 2 4 2 3 4 4 2017-12-28 00:00:00

Comment: Then please [edit] your question to include what you tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `NOW()` and it will add the current date time

Your query should take the form

```
INSERT INTO customer_order (idCustomer_Order,Customer_id,Total_Amount,Payment,Order_date,Order_month,Order_year,Delivery_date,Delivery_month,Delivery_year,product_id,OrderDate)value(3,1,122,'payed',3,2,4,2,3,4,4, NOW())
```

Answer (score 1):

I am using curDate() so that only date was inserting in database instead if i use 
current_timestamp() than i get date as well as time.

```
insert into customer_order (OrderDate)value(current_timestamp())
```

Output is   2017-12-28 01:48:31